Get woocommerce order id after "woocommerce_checkout_place_order"
I would like to create an event for the datalayer immediately after clicking the button to place an order:
function add_order_processed_event( $order_id ) {
    // Get the order object instance
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Send data to the data layer before opening the payment page
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'pre_purchase',
            'order_id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>',
            'order_total': '<?php echo $order_total; ?>'
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'add_order_processed_event' );

I'm using "woocommerce_checkout_order_processed" because that's when I can retrieve the order_id and order_totals.
However, the JavaScript code doesn't seem to execute, and all I receive in the console is the displayed JavaScript code as text:
Fixed malformed JSON. Original:
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'pre_purchase',
        'order_id': '231768',
        'order_total': '1838.00'
    });
</script>
    {"result":"success","redirect":"https:\/\/new.domain.come\/order\/pay\/231768\/?key=wc_order_oFmMMlCs228ol","order_id":231768}

It seems like it's not executing, but only showing as text.
How can I make the code creating the datalayer execute so that I can assign Google Ads conversion to the pre_purchase event in the tag manager?

This is only possible in WooCommerce Order received page (thankyou)… You can use woocommerce_thankyou hook.

The woocommerce_thankyou hook is useless for me because not everyone wants to return to the thank you page after a successful payment, which causes me to lose conversions from Google Ads. Why can't I use "woocommerce_checkout_order_processed" since it provides the order_id, which I need as the transaction_id?

Because those hooks are not to display things in frontend. There are made to process WC order data. If the customer leave the website after paying and doesn't go to order received, there is no way to get conversions from Google Ads.

@LoicTheAztec Is there a way to show the thank you page first, and then redirect to the payment afterward?

No because order received page (thankyou) is displayed after the payment process (as a redirection from the payment gateway).

maybe try wp_remote_get() to get your conversion from serverside ? Maybe test with woocommerce_payment_complete action ? I havent tested this way but could work..
